# Run electrode-native getting following error : using command **sudo ern run-android** on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, walmart-electrode, electrode-native

Getting these error when execute the command: **ern run-android**

```
$ sudo ern run-android
```

[image]

I am using installation step from this link [click here](https://dev.to/jadolg/how-to-install-electrode-native-on-ubuntu-to-develop-for-android-1m2a) . 
Please help to run application.

Comment: Did you try this? `ern create-miniapp MyGreatApp => cd MyGreatApp => ern run-android`

Comment: yes tried same step.

Comment: You can try `npm install -g  ern` ??

Comment: already used this ern.. problem after executing this command ern run-android

Answer (score 0):

Above raised issue has been resolved and following step need to follow:

open the terminal and type **sudo su** to become the root user

```
Install the gradle
```

Add SDk path on the ~/.bashrc and add the followings

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/pchauhan/Android/Sdk
```

also if in case still getting error add following line added as well

```
GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle 
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/gradle5.5
```

//comment enter the respective path as you have installed

Save the file
Reboot the system if not not source .baserc // means not set path 
again login with root user into the terminal and execute following command once after connecting the mobile device

```
$ adb devices
```

now run the command

```
ern run-android
```